# jQuery: clone HTML with information from Object Literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following HTML that I want to repeat 5 times within a div container (.container).

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="name">Name</div>
   <div class="content>Content</div>
</div>
```

I have the following object literal:

```
var main_content = {
    "content_1": {
        "name": "Joe",
        "position": "Baker"
    },
    "content_2": {
        "name": "Jane",
        "position": "Waitress"
    }
     "content_3", etc
}
```

I want to clone the top HTML and for each block, change the name and content to its respective object literal item. So I want the output of the HTML to look like below. How can I do this?

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="name">Joe</div>
   <div class="position>Baker</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <div class="name">Jane</div>
   <div class="position>Waitress</div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not, I'd say bust open [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be relatively easy using jQuery. Will this work for you?

```
for(var i in main_content)
{
    var name = main_content[i].name,
    position = main_content[i].position,

    template = $('<div class="block">\
                      <div class="name">'+name+'</div>\
                      <div class="position">'+position+'</div>\
                  </div>');

    template.appendTo($('.container'));
}
```

Please see the working jsFiddle demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/jLPkS/

Answer (score 1):

dont append to the DOM in a loop:

```
var block, resultHtml = '';
for(block in main_content){
  resultHtml += '<div class="block"><div class="name">' + main_content[block].name + '</div><div class="position">' + main_content[block].position + '</div></div>'
}
$('your-selector').append(resultHtml);
```

Comment: Interested in your argument against appending to the DOM inside a loop?

Comment: performance, see this: http://stage.learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/